# Send json to another server using asp.net core mvc c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

sorry for my english.

I need to send json to another server.

Example: 127.0.0.1/api/start

In this other server i have the service that i created running, the service need to get a json

Example {"ServerId":"1","ServerPort":"27015"}

How can i do this?

I know send json with jquery, but i want know how do this using asp.net core without use jquery. is possible?

```
    public IActionResult Start()
    {

       // Code here

        return View();
    }
```

I need to do this code using asp.net core

```
var arr = { ServerId : '1', ServerPort : '27015'};
            console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));            
            return jQuery.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': '13.77.102.81/Api/MTA/Start',
                'data': JSON.stringify(arr),
                'dataType': 'json',
                'success': function (msg) {
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  have to change your method  something like this

```
public IActionResult Start()
    {


     var jsonRequest = Json(new { ServerId = "1", ServerPort = "27015" }).Value.ToString();
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://13.77.102.81/api/mta/start ");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                          .Accept
                          .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header

                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "relativeAddress");

                    request.Content = new StringContent(jsonRequest,
                                                        Encoding.UTF8,
                                                        "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header

                    client.SendAsync(request)
                          .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                          {
                               //here your response 
                              Debug.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);
                          });
        return View();
    }
```

and here the response

```
Response: StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Date: Sun, 26 Feb 2017 21:43:26 GMT
  Server: nginx/1.4.6
  Server: (Ubuntu)
  Content-Length: 0
}
```

so your server is not running or your proxy does filters on requests :)

> **Do not expose your IP when you ask a question**

Comment: hm.. but the ip that i need send json is 13.77.102.81, where i specific this?

Comment: to be more exact is 13.77.102.81/api/mta/start

Comment: you want to send or your service send a get request ? there are 2 things

Comment: i'm sending the json on server A to server B.

Comment: i want to send the json to another server.

Comment: how your service is listening ? you are missing a piece

Comment: are you using kestrel self host or httpserver

Comment: I added another code that I created in jquery, I want to do something like this in asp.net core

Comment: Thank you, I have no problem in exposing the ip, this server is just test.

Comment: Another question, when I send this json I will get a return also in json, what variable will it return? example.

{"ServerId":"1","ServerPort":"27015"}

will return

{"sucess":"true","online":"true"}

Where can I treat this return?